# Vue components: Using slots within slots

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have v-data-table as its own component to make it more generic for my components. I would like to have the option to provide that component how each item in the table is formatted. That would be done with a slot. But the problem is, that the provided slot has a slot for v-data-table. See the example, this is difficult to explain.

In my DataTable component I have:

```
     <v-data-table 
        :headers="tableHeaders" 
        :items="items" 
        :item-key="itemKey"
        :loading="isLoading" 
        v-model="selectedRows" 
        show-select
    >        
        <!-- What do i put here? -->
    </v-data-table>
```

And I use that data table from my other component like this:

```
    <data-table
        :table-headers="tableHeaders"
        :items="messages"
        :is-loading="isLoading"
        :selected-rows="selectedRows"
        :item-key="'MessageID'"
    >        
        <template v-slot:item.actions="{ item }">
            <v-btn :to="`messages/${item.MessageID}`" icon>
                <v-icon>mdi-chevron-right</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
        </template>
        <template v-slot:item.CreatedDateTime="{ item }">
            <span>{{ format(new Date(item.CreatedDateTime)) }}</span>
        </template>
    </data-table>
```

I need the result to be rendered as:

```
     <v-data-table 
        :headers="tableHeaders" 
        :items="items" 
        :item-key="itemKey"
        :loading="isLoading" 
        v-model="selectedRows" 
        show-select
    >        
        <template v-slot:item.actions="{ item }">
            <v-btn :to="`messages/${item.MessageID}`" icon>
                <v-icon>mdi-chevron-right</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
        </template>
        <template v-slot:item.CreatedDateTime="{ item }">
            <span>{{ format(new Date(item.CreatedDateTime)) }}</span>
        </template>
    </v-data-table>
```

So the problem is, how do I provide the templates within data-table tag to be rendered within v-data-table tag?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. I found a solution utilizing the `$scopedSlotes` object, like this:

```
<v-data-table 
  :headers="tableHeaders" 
  :items="items" 
  :item-key="itemKey"
  :loading="isLoading" 
  v-model="selectedRows" 
  show-select
>        
  <template
    v-for="slot in Object.keys($scopedSlots)"
    :slot="slot"
    slot-scope="scope"
  >
    <slot
      :name="slot"
      v-bind="scope"
    ></slot>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Answer (score -1):

You will have to re-expose the slots in your "wrapper" component:

```html
<v-data-table 
  :headers="tableHeaders" 
  :items="items" 
  :item-key="itemKey"
  :loading="isLoading" 
  v-model="selectedRows" 
  show-select
>        
  <template v-slot:body="bodyParams">
    <slot name="body" v-bind="bodyParams" />
  </template>
  <template v-slot:expanded-item="expandedParams">
    <slot name="expanded-item" v-bind="expandedParams" />
  </template>
  <template v-slot:header="headerParams">
    <slot name="header" v-bind="headerParams" />
  </template>
  <template v-slot:footer="footerParams">
    <slot name="footer" v-bind="footerParams" />
  </template>
  <template v-slot:item="itemParams">
    <slot name="item" v-bind="itemParams" />
  </template>
  <template v-slot:progress="progressParams">
    <slot name="progress" v-bind="progressParams" />
  </template>
  <!-- put here the other slots you are interested in -->
</v-data-table>
```

Comment: Ok, but how do I provide the slots from the parent component?

Comment: I mean, in the component where I have <data-table ...><template...</datatable>

Comment: `<data-table ...> <template v-slot:item={item}"> <td>{{ item.messageID }}</td> </template></data-table>`